# How do I compare two arrays element-wise in Python using specific rules?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, compare

Let's say I have:

```
numpy.random.seed(20)
a=numpy.random.rand(5000)
b=numpy.random.rand(5000)
```

I want to get the indices of a where `a[x] > b[x]`, i.e. all x's

Furthermore, I want to get the indices of a where `(a[x-1] < b[x-1]) && (a[x] > b[x])`.

Can someone please help?  I've got a feeling I have to use masked arrays, but I can't quite figure out how.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First is straightforward, use `numpy.where`:

```
>>> numpy.where(a>b)
(array([   0,    1,    2, ..., 4993, 4994, 4999]),)
```

For second one you can start with

```
>>> np.where((a>b) & (np.roll(a, 1) < np.roll(b, 1)))
(array([   5,    9,   17, ..., 4988, 4991, 4999]),)
```

but you have to treat corner cases separately.

Once again, @askewchan came with correct expression for second, while I failed to add 1 properly :)

```
>>> np.where((a[1:] > b[1:]) & (a[:-1] < b[:-1]))[0] + 1
array([   5,    9,   17, ..., 4988, 4991, 4999])
```

Comment: or `np.where((a[1:] > b[1:]) & (a[:-1] < b[:-1]))[0] + 1` for the second case.

Comment: Thank you.  Is there a use of masked arrays here, or was I barking up the wrong tree?  (I'm new to Python)

Comment: @user2974839, you're using _boolean masks_, if you look at each of those comparisons (try `print a>b`), but they're not truly [`MaskedArray`s](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.html), which you definitely do not need here.

Comment: Haha, now I really hope that `+1` is correct :P  @user2974839 should doublecheck the results.

Comment: @askewchan I checked, and corrected answer, as there were wrong comparator in **my** expression

Comment: Yes, I checked both answers matched before @askewchan corrected his/her typo!  That's when I gave the +1.  Anyway, am I completely off the mark with masked arrays?  If so, what are they used for?

Comment: @user2974839, It depends on what you want to do with these indices.  Your question just asked for which indices match the condition, not how to do stuff with them.  If you want to be using `a` and `b` a lot with only the parts showing that match the condition, it might be a good use for masked arrays, but right now you can just access the matching indices by saving the index array `m = np.where(...)` and then using it to index the arrays: `a[m]` will be the values in `a` where your condition holds, and `b[m]` for those in `b`.